# Field valued points of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

So this is a [follow](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241495/what-are-the-invertible-speck-modules-k-field) up investigation on invertible modules on $Spec(K)$. Now I wish to understand
$$Mor(Spec K, \Bbb P^n_{\Bbb Z})$$
which I have [learnt](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01ND) is

> represented by the set of morphisms
> $$ \bigoplus^n_0 K  \rightarrow  K $$
> this is given by set of maps $(e_0,\ldots, e_n)$ where $e_i \in K$ and some $e_j \not=0$. Up to $K$-isomoprhisms $\beta:K^{n+1} \rightarrow K^{n+1}$, where $\beta(v_i)=e_i$.

This is supposed to [equal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functorial+geometry) to, according to nlab,

> the set of lines through the origin in $K^{n+1}$

Edit: Now what I don't see is how the equivalence $\beta$ is equivalent to scalar multiplication -  shouldn't our relation in the first case be: $v \sim w$ iff exists $A \in GL(n+1)$, $Av=w$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation of the property in your link is flawed. What it written there implies that the morphisms $\operatorname{Spec}(K)\to \mathbb{P}^n$ correspond to $(n+1)$-uples of sections of $\mathcal{O}_K$ (because it is the only invertible module, as you identified) over $\operatorname{Spec}(K)$ which generate the module, so indeed elements $(e_0,\dots,e_n)\in K^{n+1}$ with not all $e_i$ equal to $0$, and $(e_0,\dots,e_n)$ gives the same element as $(f_0,\dots,f_n)$ if there is an automorphism of $\mathcal{O}_K$ that sends $e_i$ to $f_i$. Now such an automorphism is indeed a scalar multiplication.

Comment: ah yes, you are right - but my problem is I don't see how this set of automorphism is scalar multiplication

Comment: Well, they are basically automorphisms of $K$ as a $K$-vector space.

Comment: so shouldn't we quotient out by the relation that for $v,w \in K^{n+1}$,  $v \sim w$ if and onyl if exists $A \in GL(n+1)$, $Av=w$?

Comment: No, you are confusing "an automorphism $f$ of $K^{n+1}$ such that $f(v_0,\dots,v_n) = (w_0,\dots,w_n)$" and "an automorphism $f$ of $K$ such that $f(v_i)=w_i$ for all $i$".